# в WPF C# при закруглении краев у календаря, появляется белая рамка

Tags: c#, wpf, border, calendar

Здраствуйте, решила в WPF C# закруглить края у календаря, с помощью ответов на этом сайте у меня получилось однако появилась какая-то белая рамка внутри вроде везде выключила рамку, но что-то все равно не так. Не судите строго пожалуйста только учусь

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestDiplom.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTestDiplom"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CalendarStyletest" TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF333333"/>
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFE4EAF0" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFECF0F4" Offset="0.16"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFCFCFD" Offset="0.16"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="25">
                            <StackPanel x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
                                <CalendarItem x:Name="PART_CalendarItem" Style="{TemplateBinding CalendarItemStyle}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Calendar Style="{DynamicResource CalendarStyletest}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="168,49,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: фото календаря с рамкой]

Answer (score 1):

я вроде разобралась оставлю ответ для тех кто тоже столкнется с такой проблемой, как я и подозревала проблема была в стиле элементов внутри, как раз у них была белая рамка, для этого выбираем изменить шаблон дополнительных элементов -> изменить CalendarItem -> копии;
[image: путь настроек]

находим где есть рамки (Borders) и я везде поменяла цвет на прозрачный, решение наверно кривое, буду рада более элегантным ответам (только начала работать с wpf и xaml
[image: Borders]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)